# How to download the Latex file of an article from arXiv.org?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, online-resources

It is a non-mathematical question. Math StackExchange is a not a right place to ask this question, but I don't have any other choice.

How to download the Latex file of an article from arXiv.org?

Comment: The FAQs say that TeX source is available, see here: http://arxiv.org/help/view

Comment: I see the "Other format" page : http://arxiv.org/format/hep-th/9901001v3 .But I can't find it helpful.

Comment: Like Rogelio has said in their answer, you have to click "Download source". You may also have to rename the file to have extension ".tar.gz" in order to be able to open it properly.

Comment: Would this question maybe be a better fit for Academia? After all they [have arxiv tag](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arxiv). I have also [asked in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42222562#42222562) what the users of that site think.

Answer (score 16):

It is possible, but not in all articles. You have to go to the page where the abstract is shown, click on Download -> Other Formats -> Source -> Download source.  Sometimes the source is compressed and may need unzipping.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to comment this on the answer by Rogelio expanding on the comment from Josh, but do not have enough reputation.

Following their answer to download the source for this paper https://arxiv.org/format/1706.03762 gave me a file called `1706.03762`which windows identified as a file of type "03762 File". I changed the name of the file to end in `.tar.gz`, which gave a [warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHpt8.png). This changed the file to type `GZ file`. I extracted it using 7-Zip; inside of the unzipped folder was a `TAR File` which I again extracted using 7-Zip; inside of this unzipped folder was the source code.